# Confusion on Private Method Using or Not-using function

Tags: javascript, oop, class

I didn't take any official course of Javascript.

I often read this in tutorials:

```
function Bank(name) {
   this.name = name;
   var balance = 100;

   // *my question here* method to access balance
   this.getBalance = function() {
       return balance * 0.9 ;
   };
}

var myBank = new Bank("My Bank");
console.log( myBank.getBalance() );
```

Why do developers use getBalance() instead of getBalance?

I think "getBalance" is easier to read, but no tutorial use this:

```
// *my question here* method to access balance
   this.getBalance = balance * 0.9 ;
```

then

```
console.log( myBank.getBalance );
```

I didn't see any tutorial to write using above style, even it is simpler. So:

**Is there any different between 2 style of codes? Is there any concern to avoid `.getBalance` to operate the private variable?**

Thanks in advance to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must understand the different between variable, function and function call. This is variable:

```
this.getBalance = balance * 0.9 ;
```

The value of `getBalance` variable is computed once when the code is executed. Every time you access `getBalance` (without parentheses), previously computed value is returned.

There is an important implication of using `getBalance` variable. If you modify underlying `balance` variable in the future, `getBalance` won't reflect that change because it was computed using old `balance` value.

In the case below:

```
this.getBalance = function() {
   return balance * 0.9 ;
};
```

`getBalance` is also variable but it points to a function, not to a simple value. If you access it like variable, you will get a function reference:

```
var fun = this.getBalance
```

You can now call that function using `fun()`, but `fun` reference itself (same as `this.getBalance`) isn't very useful in your case.

And of course you can call the function by using `this.getBalance()`. The semantic difference is as follows: every time you call `getBalance()`, the body of the function is executed. This means the value of `balance` is read again and `getBalance()` return value is always up to date.

As you can see there is a huge difference between assigning a function and assigning a simple value (like number) to a variable. Depending on which approach you choose, it will have different implications. You must learn about functional side of JavaScript in order to fully utilize its power.

Comment: And even if the code actually returned the balance without doing any calculations, using a getter method helps future proof the code: there will be no need to rewrite code using the class if the public instance variable needs to be converted to a method that does some computation as well.

Comment: To both of you, thank you for your explanation. I learn a lot! It is clear that we should use a function for future expansion, and for prudence (at least for me). :)